# Convergence of a series involving a ratio of sines

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Does the series

$$
  \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}$$

converge? Wolfram alpha says it does by comparison, and I was trying to compare this by saying it is less than $ 1/n^3/\sin(1/n)$ but now I'm stuck. Can someone walk me through determining the convergence of this series? A formal description if possible please, I know that $\sin(1/n)$ will behave like $1/n$ for large n so the overall sum should behave like the convergent $1/n^2$; but how can we show this formally?

Comment: $\sin x\sim x$ when $x\to0$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** We can do a Limit Comparison with $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$, written as $\sum \left(\frac{1}{1/n}\cdot \frac{1}{n^3}\right)$.

Or else note that $0\lt \sin\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)\lt \frac{1}{n^3}$ and $\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\gt \frac{1}{2n}$. That will give us a useful Comparison.

Comment: Oh I see, let me try that with the 2n comparison. That looks promising.

Comment: Using the second option, you get that the generic term is positive and $\lt \frac{2}{n^2}$. Game over.

Comment: That was extremely easy once I used that inequality, thank you very much! I will keep that inequality in mind for the future, I didn't think of that fact.

Comment: You are welcome. The Limit Comparison is also technically easy, write $1/n^2$ as $1/(1/n)\cdot (1/n^3)$.